# What is the source of nonstationarity in this VAR model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am trying to forecast a VAR model, which consists out of 5 variables with a monthly frequency. The problem is that the VAR model produces an unstable forecast and I am not sure what the source of nonstationarity might be. I checked for:

- unit roots
- timevarying variance
- multicollinearity
- structural breaks

nothing is present, but the VAR model still suffers from nonstationarity (some roots of the companion matrix are larger than one in absolute value and the forecast is exploding). What might be the source of nonstationarity?

Thank in advance!

**R-Code:**

```
# clear workspace and console
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")  

# package
library(vars)

# load data
[...]

# check unit roots (no unit roots)
for (i in 1:dim(data)[2]){
  # Null hypothesis: Series has a unit-root
  print(PP.test(data[,i]))
}

# check multicollinearity
# regress each variable on another and extract r squared
for (j in 1:dim(data)[2]){

  for (i in 1:dim(data)[2]){

    if (i != j){
      print(summary(lm(data[,i] ~ data[,j]))$r.squared)

    }
  }
}

# correlation matrix
cor(data)

# estimate VAR
VARselect(data)
VAR.estimation <- VAR(data, p=7)
VAR.prediction <- predict(VAR.estimation)


# check roots (some roots are >1)
roots(VAR.estimation)

# check stability (seems legit)
plot(stability(VAR.estimation))

# check ARCH effetcs
arch.test(VAR.estimation)
```

**Code executed:**

```
> 
> # package
> library(vars)
> 
> # load data
> [...]
> 
> # check unit roots (no unit roots)
> for (i in 1:dim(data)[2]){
+   # Null hypothesis: Series has a unit-root
+   print(PP.test(data[,i]))
+ }

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  data[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -5.2709, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value
= 0.01


    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  data[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -9.7965, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value
= 0.01


    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  data[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -12.633, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value
= 0.01


    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  data[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = -5.8196, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value
= 0.01


    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  data[, i]
Dickey-Fuller = 1.8708, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value
= 0.99

> 
> # check multicollinearity
> # regress each variable on another and extract r squared
> for (j in 1:dim(data)[2]){
+   
+   for (i in 1:dim(data)[2]){
+     
+     if (i != j){
+       print(summary(lm(data[,i] ~ data[,j]))$r.squared)
    +           
    +     }
    +   }
    + }
    [1] 0.6008077
    [1] 0.03328728
    [1] 0.00629842
    [1] 0.008179985
    [1] 0.6008077
    [1] 0.007497181
    [1] 0.2706427
    [1] 0.08125828
    [1] 0.03328728
    [1] 0.007497181
    [1] 0.07136442
    [1] 0.001914882
    [1] 0.00629842
    [1] 0.2706427
    [1] 0.07136442
    [1] 0.04056236
    [1] 0.008179985
    [1] 0.08125828
    [1] 0.001914882
    [1] 0.04056236
    > 
    > # correlation matrix
    > cor(data)
                 Production      Demand Stockchange      Export
    Production   1.00000000  0.77511788  0.18244801 -0.07936259
    Demand       0.77511788  1.00000000 -0.08658626 -0.52023330
    Stockchange  0.18244801 -0.08658626  1.00000000 -0.26714120
    Export      -0.07936259 -0.52023330 -0.26714120  1.00000000
    Import      -0.09044327  0.28505839 -0.04375936 -0.20140101
                     Import
    Production  -0.09044327
    Demand       0.28505839
    Stockchange -0.04375936
    Export      -0.20140101
    Import       1.00000000
    > 
    > # estimate VAR
    > VARselect(data)
    $selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     9      7      4      8 

$criteria
                 1            2            3           4           5
AIC(n)    10.39522     9.745212     9.688002    7.067020    6.944198
HQ(n)     10.65632    10.223886    10.384254    7.980851    8.075608
SC(n)     11.03772    10.923124    11.401328    9.315761    9.728353
FPE(n) 32712.32541 17102.550733 16211.479755 1187.340187 1062.110437
                 6          7          8          9         10
AIC(n)    6.953560   6.124008   6.033379   6.005920   6.042919
HQ(n)     8.302549   7.690576   7.817526   8.007646   8.262223
SC(n)    10.273130   9.978992  10.423778  10.931734  11.504146
FPE(n) 1090.416764 487.149240 459.453273 466.170956 510.405428

> VAR.estimation <- VAR(data, p=7)
> VAR.prediction <- predict(VAR.estimation)
> 
> 
> # check roots (some roots are >1)
> roots(VAR.estimation)
 [1] 2.0393581 1.5368379 1.5368379 1.3211836 1.1095403 1.0548146
 [7] 1.0548146 1.0012034 0.9056210 0.9056210 0.8956091 0.8956091
[13] 0.8901330 0.8879853 0.8879853 0.8830325 0.8830325 0.8747671
[19] 0.8747671 0.8740473 0.8740473 0.8679999 0.8679999 0.8544342
[25] 0.8544342 0.8536405 0.8536405 0.8439661 0.8439661 0.8085204
[31] 0.8085204 0.6709678 0.6709678 0.6009885 0.4600153
> 
> # check stability (seems legit)
> plot(stability(VAR.estimation))
Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin"
> 
> # check ARCH effetcs
> arch.test(VAR.estimation)

    ARCH (multivariate)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR.estimation
Chi-squared = 1088.703, df = 1125, p-value = 0.7762
```

**Data:**

```
A   B   C   D   E
14.45   9.066666667 51  3.683333333 0
14.25806452 9.048387097 8.5 4.935483871 0
13.31666667 8.783333333 8.5 4.25    0
10.14516129 8.225806452 -76.5   4.387096774 0
19.19354839 9.596774194 153 4.661290323 0
16.71666667 9.916666667 42.5    5.383333333 0
15.90322581 9.322580645 8.5 6.306451613 0
18.13333333 11.05   0   7.083333333 0
12.33870968 9.048387097 -68 5.483870968 0
13.70967742 9.596774194 17  3.290322581 0
16.08928571 10.92857143 34  3.946428571 0
17.82258065 10.14516129 -42.5   9.048387097 0
20.11666667 9.916666667 -25.5   11.05   0
13.70967742 9.048387097 -51 6.306451613 0
17  10.2    59.5    4.816666667 0
15.90322581 12.33870968 -68 5.758064516 0
17.27419355 11.51612903 34  4.661290323 0
20.11666667 11.9    76.5    5.666666667 0
16.4516129  10.69354839 8.5 5.483870968 0
15.3    10.76666667 8.5 4.25    0
17.82258065 9.048387097 25.5    7.951612903 0
12.33870968 8.5 -161.5  8.774193548 0
16.12068966 9.086206897 34  5.862068966 0
20.83870968 9.596774194 85  8.5 0
16.71666667 11.33333333 -34 6.516666667 0
19.19354839 9.048387097 17  9.596774194 0
22.1    11.9    17  9.35    0
21.11290323 14.25806452 -93.5   9.870967742 0
23.03225806 13.16129032 25.5    9.048387097 0
20.96666667 9.35    8.5 11.33333333 0
22.75806452 14.53225806 -51 10.14516129 0
22.1    11.05   -8.5    11.33333333 0
20.56451613 8.774193548 110.5   8.225806452 0
16.72580645 12.88709677 85  1.096774194 0
9.714285714 11.53571429 -51 0   0
15.35483871 12.88709677 -93.5   5.483870968 0
25.5    15.86666667 0   9.633333333 0
25.22580645 11.24193548 -42.5   15.35483871 0
24.08333333 11.61666667 8.5 12.18333333 0
23.03225806 15.90322581 -51 8.774193548 0
21.93548387 17  -25.5   5.758064516 0
21.25   13.6    127.5   3.4 0
24.12903226 15.62903226 51  6.85483871  0
21.81666667 10.76666667 -93.5   14.16666667 0
23.85483871 12.33870968 136 7.129032258 0
18.37096774 13.70967742 144.5   0   0
13.66071429 11.53571429 -17 2.732142857 0
14.80645161 13.16129032 -102    4.935483871 0
22.95   17.56666667 -76.5   7.933333333 0
29.33870968 14.80645161 76.5    12.06451613 0
22.38333333 13.03333333 -136    13.6    0
27.41935484 18.91935484 76.5    6.032258065 0
28.79032258 20.83870968 -119    11.51612903 0
26.91666667 13.03333333 153 8.783333333 0
29.06451613 26.0483871  -93.5   6.032258065 0
29.18333333 18.7    0   10.48333333 0
27.41935484 20.01612903 -51 9.048387097 0
21.93548387 14.53225806 170 1.919354839 0
13.66071429 15.78571429 -136    2.732142857 0
23.85483871 15.90322581 8.5 7.403225806 0
28.9    17.85   119 7.083333333 0
29.88709677 16.72580645 -170    18.64516129 0
33.15   18.7    -59.5   16.43333333 0
26.0483871  18.91935484 -25.5   7.951612903 0
30.43548387 23.03225806 68  5.209677419 0
30.31666667 19.83333333 51  8.783333333 0
28.79032258 20.56451613 0   8.225806452 0
22.1    18.41666667 -93.5   7.083333333 0
25.77419355 20.83870968 110.5   1.370967742 0
18.64516129 15.08064516 93.5    0.274193548 0
25.79310345 17.5862069  110.5   4.396551724 0
29.88709677 20.56451613 -68 11.51612903 0
30.03333333 23.8    -110.5  9.916666667 0
30.98387097 16.4516129  51  12.61290323 0
30.31666667 17.56666667 17  11.61666667 0
31.80645161 30.16129032 -76.5   3.838709677 0
29.88709677 23.30645161 -25.5   7.403225806 0
32.01666667 21.25   -34 11.9    0
32.35483871 23.30645161 0   9.048387097 0
33.43333333 24.08333333 0   9.35    0
34.27419355 23.58064516 0   10.41935484 0
29.06451613 17.27419355 127.5   7.677419355 0
24.28571429 19.125  0   5.160714286 0
26.87096774 18.64516129 85  5.209677419 0
24.93333333 22.66666667 -102    5.95    0
27.96774194 21.66129032 17  5.483870968 0
28.9    20.68333333 0   8.216666667 0
29.88709677 27.14516129 -102    6.032258065 0
32.35483871 26.0483871  -17 7.129032258 0
31.16666667 21.53333333 102 6.233333333 0
30.43548387 23.85483871 8.5 5.758064516 0
28.61666667 24.08333333 25.5    3.683333333 0
28.79032258 25.77419355 0   3.016129032 0
28.51612903 20.56451613 144.5   2.741935484 0
27.01785714 19.125  153 2.428571429 0
27.96774194 24.67741935 -8.5    3.564516129 0
29.75   22.38333333 59.5    5.1 0
25.5    23.85483871 -68 3.838709677 0
28.05   26.91666667 -76.5   3.683333333 0
31.25806452 27.69354839 -8.5    3.838709677 0
29.61290323 26.0483871  -34 4.935483871 0
31.16666667 25.78333333 -17 6.233333333 0
29.33870968 25.77419355 -68 5.758064516 0
30.6    26.35   -34 5.383333333 0
29.88709677 26.32258065 -76.5   6.032258065 0
29.33870968 21.93548387 204 0.548387097 0
18.21428571 23.07142857 -153    0.303571429 0
28.24193548 25.22580645 -8.5    3.290322581 0
28.9    26.35   0   2.55    0
31.53225806 28.51612903 8.5 2.467741935 0
27.2    24.65   -34 3.4 0
32.62903226 33.4516129  -170    4.661290323 0
32.08064516 26.87096774 144.5   0.274193548 0
35.7    29.46666667 119 1.7 0
33.72580645 28.79032258 110.5   1.370967742 0
29.18333333 29.46666667 -93.5   2.833333333 0
33.17741935 28.24193548 85  1.919354839 0
24.67741935 25.22580645 -59.5   1.370967742 0
24.03448276 20.22413793 42.5    2.051724138 0
28.79032258 27.41935484 0   1.370967742 0
27.76666667 29.18333333 -85 1.416666667 0
32.35483871 28.51612903 42.5    2.193548387 0
30.03333333 32.01666667 -119    1.983333333 0
31.80645161 32.35483871 -34 0.548387097 0
35.64516129 33.72580645 0   1.64516129  0
32.86666667 31.45   -34 2.55    0
28.24193548 27.96774194 0   0   0
31.73333333 31.45   8.5 0   0
31.53225806 29.88709677 25.5    0.548387097 0
33.4516129  31.53225806 34  0.548387097 0
32.17857143 38.25   -170    0   0
32.08064516 29.33870968 51  0.822580645 0
30.6    27.76666667 85  0   0.283333333
32.62903226 29.61290323 76.5    0.548387097 0
35.7    28.61666667 187 0.85    0
31.25806452 24.9516129  161.5   1.096774194 0
30.43548387 22.48387097 221 0.548387097 0
35.13333333 32.58333333 51  0.283333333 0
32.35483871 34.82258065 -76.5   0   0
32.86666667 34  -8.5    0.85    1.7
33.17741935 30.70967742 59.5    0   0
32.62903226 30.70967742 51  0   0
23.67857143 26.71428571 -51 0.303571429 1.517857143
29.61290323 35.37096774 238 0   13.16129032
26.35   35.13333333 -8.5    0   8.216666667
11.24193548 35.64516129 -229.5  0   16.4516129
```

Comment: If you want to check for multicollinearity, estimating pairwise correlations is not enough. Even if any two variables are not multicollinear, a combination of three or more may be. You could try `vif` function from `car` library.

Comment: And if multicollinearity is not an issue, perhaps you could choose a different lag order for you model to, at least as an experiment.